# what does it mean Runner exited with value -1 in Squish for Web GUI testing tool

Tags: python, web-testing, gui-testing, squish, gui-test-framework

I executed a test case in a tetsuite from Squish IDE. Language is Python 2.6.6. I am    using EVALUATION version of Squish on Windows 7.

```
Error log:

 2013-11-27T14:40:53    START       Start ''                        Test '' started
R: 2013-11-27T14:40:53  FATAL       Starting application            Application'<my application name>' could not be started. An error occurred while starting the AUT.
R: 2013-11-27T14:40:53  END         End of test                     Giving up after error
R: *******************************************************
R: Summary:
R: Number of Test Cases:       1
R: Number of Tests:    0
R: Number of Errors:       0
R: Number of Fatals:       1
R: Number of Fails:    0
R: Number of Passes:       0
R: Number of Expected Fails:       0
R: Number of Unexpected Passes:    0
R: Number of Warnings:     0
R: *******************************************************
R: * This is an EVALUATION version of Squish. *
R: Runner exited with value -1
S: 14:41:33:642 Debug: Connection established from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: About what does something means, a wise man once said: Google it :)

Comment: @aIKid Google is not good many times :-) I did post the question after googling besides gone through squish questions/faqs.

Comment: Exiting with -1 could mean an error. Hard to tell which particular error it refers to.

Comment: @vahancho, Did you encounter this earlier please?

Comment: @SreeRama I am getting this error in latest evaluation copy. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installed the evaluation copy after un-installing the existing and tried again.  It works.
This error is not coming in licensed version.  The exact reason for the error could not be found yet.

Comment: Tried reinstalling the evaluation copy... the error still persists...